# Recursive Array Cleanup

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have a function called combined which is going to loop through an array of orders. It is specifically searching for someone who placed more than 1 order and matches based on the customer's name and address line 1. If the customer places 2 orders this will catch them and combine them however if they have 3 or more if only catches 2. When I recursively call the function I get an invalid offset error which I do not understand as I thought the array index would refresh on every function call?

```
function combined(Array $all) {
//find any matching single orders and combine
$count = count($all);
$combinedorder = array();
for($i=1; $i < $count; $i++) {
    for($j=1; $j < $count; $j++) {
        //if order # is not the same
        if(strcasecmp($all[$i][0], $all[$j][0]) !== 0){ 
          //if name matches
            if(strcasecmp($all[$i][2], $all[$j][2]) == 0) {
              //if address line 1 matches
                if(strcasecmp($all[$i][3], $all[$j][3]) == 0) {
                    $combinedorder[] = array('ordernos' => array($all[$i][0], $all[$j][0]), $all[$i][1], $all[$i][2], $all[$i][3], $all[$i][4], $all[$i][5], $all[$i][6], $all[$i][7], $all[$i][8], $all[$i][9], $all[$i][10], 'orders' => array($all[$i][11], $all[$j][11]));

                    unset($all[$i]);
                    unset($all[$j]);

                    $all = array_merge($all, $combinedorder);
                    $all = array_values($all);
                    reset($all);
             //this recursive call does not work. undefined offset error
                    combined($all);
                }
             }
          }
    }
}
return $all;
```

}

Comment: You need to show an example of the array and what it should look like modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-index the array. You are deleting some of the indexes with `unset($all[$i])` and `unset($all[$j])`. So when the function calls itself and your loop hits the index that you deleted you get the invalid offset error.

To fix it just add this code after you `unset` some of the indexes to reset the keys of the array.

```
$all = array_values($all);
```

Comment: I am still getting error PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 91

Comment: Can you `print_r($all)` before you call `combine()` the first time and then `print_r($all)` after you you `array_merge` inside the combine function. Then kill the script before it calls `combine()` again and edit the results into your question?

Comment: I got it. Had to reset the count variable with $count = count($all) after doing the array_values($all). Works well!

Comment: That makes sense. I forgot about `$count`.